# swiftyJSON move into array

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I try to get start with swiftyJSON and parsing information in Swift so i start with this API to understand it:

> http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

So here is my Code

```
import Fuzi
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary

    var JSON_TestURL = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //get JSON
        Alamofire.request(.GET, JSON_TestURL).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            //print(swiftyJsonVar)
            //get JSONarray Name and write it into new Array
            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }

            //count array and give "tag"
            print(self.arrRes.count)



            for var index = 0; index < self.arrRes.count; ++index {
                var dict = self.arrRes[index]
                let x = dict["name"] as? String
                print(x)
                print("")
            }
        }

    }
```

getting the name, id etc is no problem but when i try to get the phone number i can't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

```
for var index = 0; index < self.arrRes.count; ++index {
                var dict = self.arrRes[index]
                let x = dict["phone"]!["mobile"] as? String
                print(x)
                //print("")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using SwiftyJSON you don't have to cast the objects like you do with NSJSONSerialization. You don't have to use this way of looping either when a simple call to `map` will do the trick.

For example, replace all this:

```
if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
}

print(self.arrRes.count)

for var index = 0; index < self.arrRes.count; ++index {
    var dict = self.arrRes[index]
    let x = dict["phone"]!["mobile"] as? String
    print(x)
}
```

with this:

```
let contacts = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayValue
let allMobilePhones = contacts.map { $0["phone"]["mobile"].stringValue }
print(allMobilePhones)
```